# How to use input to create an object

Tags: java, object, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

I have a `CarModel` class that has three fields: `name`, `fuelEconomy`, and `gasTankSize`.

```
class CarModel {
    private String name;
    private double fuelEconomy;
    private double gasTankSize;

    CarModel(String name, double fuelEconomy, double gasTankSize) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fuelEconomy = fuelEconomy;
        this.gasTankSize = gasTankSize;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    double getFuelEconomy() {
        return fuelEconomy;
    }

    double getGasTankSize() {
        return gasTankSize;
    }
}
```

Given the input as a string of text separated by a new line:

```
MODEL Camry 6.5 58 
MODEL Civic 7.5 52
FINISH
```

How can I create a new object every time the word `MODEL` is in the input, store the model in an array, use the following words as the data for those fields and end the program when `FINISH` is in the input?

Comment: Please share the Car class.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to ask?  Do you need to know how to read user input?  How to call a constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside main method, try doing something like this (Using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
String line;
List<CarModel> cars = new ArrayList<>();
  try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){
     while(sc.hasNextLine()){
     line = sc.nextLine();
     String[] arr = line.split(" ");
     if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Model")){
        cars.add(new CarModel(arr[0], Double.parseDouble(arr[1]), Double.parseDouble(arr[2])));
      }else if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Finish"){
        break;
      }
    }
   }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
     // do something here! 
   }catch(Exception ex){
     // do something here as well!
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `String.split` method. You pass a delimiter, in your case a space character, and then the method chops the string into pieces based on your provided delimeter. Getting the input into your program depends on where the input will be coming from, whether by file or terminal or some other source.

Once you've read a line of input, call `String[] values = line.split(" ")`

Again, how to read the input depends on where the input is coming from, which you haven't specified.